# PHP's error_log() vs syslog()

Tags: php, error-logging, syslog

I'm trying to decide what functionality to use for logging to a custom file.

**Background**
We have several PHP processes, both running as Apaches (mod_php) and as Deamons (CLI, forked). I would like to be able to specify a log file per process/task to write to. For both the Apache processes as the Deamons, multiple processes will be writing to the same file.

**Options**
PHP offers both [`error_log()`](http://php.net/manual/function.error-log.php) and [`syslog()`](http://php.net/manual/function.syslog.php). Both seem to offer more or less the same functionality.

**My question**

- What are the pros and cons of those functions?
- Which one to choose? (**and why?**)
- What if I drop the requirement of multiple files?

Comment: One more option would be to set log filename as `error_log` php.ini directive (I think it worked if used as `ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/log/file')`) and using `trigger_error()` for generating error messages. This way, you would use PHP-level error logging (rather than OS-level error logging) and would not have to specify `$destination` as with `error_log()` function.

Comment: we use `trigger_error()` in combination with custom error handling functionality via `set_error_handler()`, we want this custom error handler to log to a file in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 13):

`syslog` sends the message to the OS logger, while `error_log` has multiple options, either to the OS logger, to an email, to a file, or to the SAPI logging handler, as is stated in the documentation.

Since you say yo want to write on multiple logs, I'd recommend `error_log` with `$message_type = 3`, wich lets you add messages to the file set in the `$destination` parameter.

Comment: What is the SAPI logging handler? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it might help. Do you have pros & cons as asked?  The above is mostly a summary of http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php .