# A command line works in cmd, but when i try to use it in php (exec) does not work

Tags: php, windows, command-line, cmd, xampp

I'm  using windows 10, Xampp 5.6, php 5.6 and trying to print from php using exec function to print directly with FoxItReader.

this command works well in command line:

```
foxitreader /p ticket.pdf \\DESKTOP-M1EMKH4\EPSONTMT20II
```

but when i try to execute it from php it does not work, i think that issue is related to escaping my command. Would you help me with that ?

Comment: And how do you execute that command from PHP?

Comment: because you are running the same program using a different [`SAPIs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it)

Comment: I have found in several posts that I can execute CMD command from PHP using 'exec', 'shell_exec' and 'system', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. My webserver Apache, hasn't permission to execute commands CMD like. So, in windows i went to services.msc -> Apache 2.4 -> Log On -> This Account. So then use the Administrator credentials. And that's it.

Thanks.