# How to access to apache log?

Tags: php, apache, centos

I have a centos7 and I have installed httpd and mysqld.

I wanted to access to apache log in `/var/httpd/log` with:

```
echo file_get_contents("/var/log/httpd/domains/example.com.log");
```

But it does not work.

Comment: how do you run this script? using a web browser? then you will not be able to access this file.

Comment: its run on webserver as php file.

Comment: you are not able to do this directly, web server often runs under `www-data` which has no permissions to do this, [more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it).

Comment: on other server i have centos and directadmin and in directadmin ,I able to accses the log .

Comment: You misspelled ".log".

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is in PHP syntax, is it correct?

While `file_get_contents();` can only obtain file under the **WEB ROOT** in relative link or a URI.