# october cms host migration issue PHP Fatal error

Tags: php, migration, octobercms

StackOverflow community. I have tried to transfer the October cms website from one host to another. As a result, I received 500 error. [browser error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GJCV.png)

So what was done:

1. website backup via ssh
2. database backup
3. import DB to a new host
4. website backup was restored
5. new DB credentials filled into the database.php file

then I tried to contact hostinger support team and they provide me with that answer.

> I've tried a few things, such as updating the composer and changing the PHP version, but there are still issues. On PHP 7.2 the error 500 goes away but the page displays a different error. On 8.0 the issue persists even after updating the composer.

as the result, they advised me to create a thread on this website and show the error message.

```
[05-Jun-2022 12:45:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Declaration of DateTime::modify(string $modifier) must be compatible with Carbon\CarbonInterface::modify($modify) in /home/u499609402/domains/bloommo.lt/public_html/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 0
```

can you help me to fix this?

p.s. the developer that created this October cms project left the team and had no answer to messages. So I have only access to the old server and new host.

Comment: The `browser error message` is useless. That is an error you will see for any server error. What octobercms version are you using? Perhaps you need to update that?

Comment: Looks like OctoberCMS isn't compatible with PHP8, also looks like they changed their business model and are now a SAAS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, if you are okay it may be a minor issue... please contact me at https://www.fiverr.com/users/hardik_satasiya and share your hosting details may be i can fix your issue (of course no charges) just for credential security

Answer (score 0):

Use the same PHP version on the new host that you have used on the old server.

Comment: I tried but the issue is still there. version on the old server: Php 8.0.19 on the new host is PHP 8.0 ( on new host there is no version 8.0.19 only 8.0 or 8.1)

Comment: That PHP version is way to new for the code, if you want to use it, you've to make the code compatible with that PHP version first. In my answer I was expecting you were looking just to get it run.

Comment: yep, my goal is to get it to work.  i tried to switch PHP version to 7.0 but get this message: Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.2.0". You are running 7.0.33. in /home/u499609402/domains/bloommo.lt/public_html/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

Comment: then I tried to switch to PHP 7.2 and this error message disappeared but 500 error returned. what I can do?

Comment: 500:  Check the SAPIs error log for the real error message.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, can you please navigate me to where I can check this log?

Comment: This is most often the webservers' error log (apache or nginx error log) (SAPI = Server API, compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/9948008/367456)