# I am working on Windows server migration from 2008 R2 to 2019, getting oci_pconnect error when OCI module is present

Tags: php, iis, oracle-call-interface, instantclient

I am facing a deadlock situation where when I run the `extension_loaded(oci8)` command through command prompt, it returns `true` but same the code returns `false` in a php function when loading the webpage.

I also checked php command to connect to Oracle DB and I was successful. But the same `oci_pconnect` throws a fatal error when called in a php function.

PHP version - 5.6.3 (x86), oracle instant client 12.1 (x86).

Configured FastCGI in IIS.

Below are the commands.

```
command:
php -r "echo (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4 ? '32 bit' : '64 bit').PHP_EOL;" && php -i | findstr Thread 

Output : 
32 bit | Thread safety => disabled.
```

```
command: 
php -r "echo extension_loaded('oci8') ? 'Yes' : 'No';"
Output : 
Yes
```

```
command: 
php -r "echo oci_pconnect('uname','pwd', 'oradb') ? 'Yes' : 'No';"
Output : 
Yes
```

When the same command (`php -r "echo extension_loaded('oci8') ? 'Yes' : 'No';"`) is used in a php function it returns `No`
and the php error log shows

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Kindly let me know where I am wrong or if I need any additional set up.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between running code with different [SAPIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it) in PHP, when you are running your PHP under Web [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it), under the hood, PHP uses different configurations for each [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it). Enabling a PHP extension on a [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it) does not mean that it had been enabled on the other [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it) unless you have a built-in extension. For instance, if you built your PHP from source and included the `oci8` extension within it, this meaning that the `oci8` will be available through all different [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it). On the other hand, if you are using `oci8` as an extension, this means that you will need to enable / disable it for every different [SAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it).

Basically PHP comes with a popular [SAPIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it) like: apache2, cli, and fpm. if you want to use a specific extension on cli, you will need to explicitly enable it on cli, if you want to enable it on apache2 or fpm (for nginx), you will need to explicitly enable it for them too.

Comment: I have enabled php-fpm through command line bat script. still face the same.

Comment: You need to enable `oci8` extension on the PHP-FPM configurations file.

Comment: in PHPINFO(), Server API shows Command Line Interface. bit confused.
what configuration changes should i make

Comment: Any steps to enable  PHP extension through CLI ?

Comment: @naveenkanni https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php please pay attention to how to enable the extension after installing it