# OPcache settings for drupal -which file? and what are the proper setting?

Tags: php, drupal, opcache

First of all, i need to say:
"It's been a long time since I installed last time drupal"
The last Drupal I used was Drupal 7.

I already spent 1 week to try and retry again.
(by reinstalling about 10 times from zero Ubuntu 22.04 with Nginx)
(consulting 7 different guides and all of them had some mistakes)
Now, **I was able to install Drupal10 and make it work.**
But I want more: activate **OPcache**

On my server I have **2 php.ini** :

/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini

/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini

I guess the one responsible for Drupal is the second one: /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini
But I am not sure and I am asking you

Both of the files have OPcache online
**1765**
but which one do I need to modify?
it is for sure /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini ?

**For the settings,** I found this:

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.fast_shutdown=1
```

Is it correct? or i need modify something else?

Thank to all that help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is SAPI and when would you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948008/what-is-sapi-and-when-would-you-use-it)

Comment: to be honest .... no!

Comment: Well, it will not give you a direct answer for your PO, but it will clarify how does PHP works under hood with different SAPIs, in a nutshell, CLI is the SAPI that will run in a shell/terminal env, FPM is the SAPI that will be invoked on a web server env. So, your edits should be within the FPM ini file. Unless you are talking about installing Drupal using a CLI or something. Not sure tho.

Comment: ok thanks. so you are not sure (like me) which file I need to modify... but you thought to send me a guide anyway. Thank you. Can you answer at least if the settings will be correct or not?

Comment: by the way, thanks for voting down to my question even if you are not sure (like me)

Comment: Take it easy, please, I did not downvote your question, and even if I did, it does not mean a bad thing about you. However, I was telling that I am not sure about if you are talking about installing Drupal using CLI, so you will need to update the CLI INI file, otherwise you will need to update the other one.

Comment: Drupal use "composer" or it's own processor like most of cms and anyway all the cms now need fastcgi. If I had just one php.ini no need to ask but I have 2. And I am not really sure which one is responsible for the cms and Drupal is like... using both of them? may be... no idea.

Comment: For Drupal CMS on the web, the FPM one is the responsible.

Comment: ok, Thanks, but I was just guessing was correct but not sure. Now, second part of question... The settings are correct or I need more?

Answer (score 0):

When running Drupal, you use PHP via both the command line (when using say drush, or just PHP in general in your shell) and also on the web server which is serving Drupal.

These days, most PHP installations use php-fpm (FastCGI Process Manager) as it's now in PHP core (now I've checked, as of 5.3.3). So the "fpm" folder relates to the PHP that your web server is using. And, in case it's not obvious, the "cli" folder relates to the PHP you use for drush/ PHP commands on the command line.

You can see that the web version is installed if you go to: /admin/reports/status/php

And the cli version using: `php --info|grep "opcache\."`

As for the settings themselves, really - it depends on your application, and how your Drupal application is set up to utilise opcache. For now, the configs you've posted are fine and just alter them in both places.